# Typescript component build error Type error: Property 'Item' does not exist on type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I know the code works in my dev server, but when its built for deploy on prd it fails with:

```
Type error: Property 'Item' does not exist on type '({ children, spacing, showDivider, alignItems }: Stack) => Element'.
  25 |     <div className="m-auto max-w-lg">
  26 |       <Stack spacing="s">
> 27 |         <Stack.Item>
```

I have this custom Stack component:

```
const Stack = ({ children, spacing = 'm', showDivider = false, alignItems }: Stack) => {
...
```

And an index.ts defined like this:

```
import Stack from './Stack';
import Item from './subcomponents/Item';

Stack.Item = Item;

export { Stack };
```

I have no idea why this failed then on build or how to fix this?

Comment: The workaround I'm using is: export default Object.assign(Stack, {Item: Item})

Comment: Ah interesting, that does resolve it, but annoying to do that as it looks weird, but i guess it will do for now unless someone else has a solution

Comment: Ideally I could ignore all this errors but from what I can tell there is no way to do it on the whole project :(

Comment: You can do it with assign operator if you do it in the same file where your main component is